# A film where a guy has to convince the robot she’s okay

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

There’s this guy trapped in an old looking house with high tech computers, and there’s this woman’s consciousness trapped inside this robot. It’s either his dead wife/girl friend and he has to convinced her of something whilst in this simulation that she’s okay, and that makes the robot work. He enters via neural transmitters, but repeatedly fails to convince her of something and the robot doesn’t work. I remember there’s a garden he sits in, and that the robot isn’t human in shape. It’s more beast like, and her consciousness is being kept alive inside.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: *You're a droid, and I'm a 'noid*

Comment: I'm surprised at how many valid answers we have...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, just based on the title, I came here thinking it could be "Toys", where Robin Williams has to briefly tell Joan Cusack's character that she'll be alright after an accident, but the info in the actual question doesn't match at all. I also thought it could be "Replicas" with Keanu Reeves, trying to convince the transferred consciousness of soldiers into a robotic body that things are perfectly fine, but that also doesn't match the details, either. Or "Ex Machina" with the AI in a female robot body, but again, it doesn't match the details. I guess this is a heavily used trope.

Comment: I think it's actually a relatively-common trope that some humanoid-looking robots don't know they are robots; they believe they are human; and if they ever find out that they are a robot, then this would cause them a major glitch, perhaps they'll cease functioning entirely.

Comment: Almost [dalek Clara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asylum_of_the_Daleks)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like Tears of Steel (2012), a short 12-minute film. It's available on YouTube.

The video thumbnail shows the distinctive "beast-like" robot her consciousness is trapped in.

Rather than convincing her "she's okay", he's trying to make peace with her after a breakup, to

> Save the world from a robot apocalypse that she's apparently causing.

Comment: Ooh, yes. This could easily be it

Comment: That’s the one! I was half convinced that is dreamt it, that’s why my description was pretty vague. Thank you for scratching the itch!

Answer (score 15):

Could this be [*Archive*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6882604/) (2020)?

> 2038: George Almore is working on a true human-equivalent AI. His
> latest prototype is almost ready. This sensitive phase is also the
> riskiest. Especially as he has a goal that must be hidden at all
> costs.

George spends time with his (dead) wife in a simulation. He's building a robot body for her to occupy.

Comment: Not the one I was thinking of, but I’ll add it to the list

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be "Transcendance", It features Johnny Depp as a scientist who studies AI and gets fatally injured, his consciousness is preserved as his mind is uploaded in an advanced computer. It also features communicating with his wife (in the form of an AI) and spending time in a garden.

Comment: I did think of this one, but it's very clearly his consciousness that's trapped, not hers

Comment: It came up a lot when I tried searching for it, but I’ll have to give it a watch now